# Parsing JSON without having to create tons of classes

Tags: entity-framework, parsing, json.net

I'm currently programming a service that is supposed to poll a number of APIs, unify the data whenever possible, and store it in my database. I would prefer to not have to create a new class for every request I make and for every subset of data I want to save out of a request. So I opted for using anonymous and dynamic types. This created the following monstrosity; possibly because I haven't been using anonymous/dynamic types for a very long time. I should also note that the function does not work, but should give a good gist of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
    public string GetActivities(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        //TODO: get statistics of today. If exists, overwrite.

        var date = DateTime.Today;
        var apiCall = String.Format("/1/user/-/activities/date/{0}.json", date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        var request = new RestRequest(apiCall);
        var response = restClient.Execute(request);

        //If the response is not what we expected (and exception gets thrown in HandleResponse), rethrow the exception. 
        try
        {
            HandleResponse(response);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }

        //Create a dynamic object from the JSON response. This way we do not need to create a new class for each response.
        dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content);

        //Create a list to add anonymous objects to. We define the prototype in Select()
        var activities = Enumerable.Empty<dynamic>()
         .Select(r => new { 
             distance = 0, 
             duration = 0, 
             hasStartTime = false, 
             startTime = DateTime.Now, 
             calories = 0, 
             steps = 0 
         }).ToList();

        //Grab the data we need from the API response
        foreach(var a in data.activities)
        {
            var act = new
            {
                distance = a.distance,
                duration = a.duration,
                hasStartTime = a.hasStartTime,
                startTime = a.startTime,
                calories = a.calories,
                steps = a.steps
            };
            activities.Add(act);
        }

        List<Statistic> statistics = new List<Statistic>();

        foreach (var a in activities)
        {
            var parsedData = new { distance = "" };

            //Add the data we received as a JSON object to the object we store in the database.
            var statistic = new Statistic()
            {
                ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Device = context.Device.Where(d => d.Name == "Fitbit").Single(),
                Timestamp = DateTime.Today,
                Type = context.StatisticType.Where(s => s.Type == "calories_eaten").Single(),
                User = user,
                Value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parsedData)
            };

            statistics.Add(statistic);
        }

        //Save the newly added data to the database.
        context.Statistic.AddRange(statistics);

        context.SaveChanges();

        return null;
    }
```

Considering the monstrosity this function has become, is there an alternative? Preferably one where I would not need to create a ton of classes.

Comment: The alternative to not creating classes is creating classes.  Depending on how similar the JSON is from each of the APIs, you might be able to make some reusable methods to handle them, but without knowing what the JSON looks like, there really isn't any way to say.  My best advice is, get this working; then get another one working, then look for similarities and factor those parts into helper methods.  Keep doing that until you've evolved your design into something that works for you.

Comment: @BrianRogers I just discovered ExpandoObjects, and they seem to be helping a lot. It helped me reduce the above method by 25 lines. And there is still some boilerplate to factor out.

Answer (score 0):

What are you actually trying to do? From reading your code it looks like you discard all the data read about activities. The only way the JSON affects the code is by the number of activities.

Is this:

```
var parsedData = new { distance = "" };
```

actually supposed to say this:

```
var parsedData = new { distance = a.distance };
```

If you're only interested in one value from the JSON you read, I suggest it would be simpler to use JSON.net LINQ. This is an interface that treats JSON like just a bunch of dictionaries (called "objects" in keeping with JS where an object is actually a dictionary) and arrays, like JSON was intended.

```
JObject data = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
JArray activities = (JArray)data["activities"];
foreach (JToken activity in activities)
{
    JObject activityObject = (JObject)activity;
    JObject parsedData = new JObject();
    parsedData["distance"] = activityObject["distance"];
    var statistic = new Statistic()
    {
        ...
        Value = parsedData.ToString();
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing what you are trying to do, but if you are using MVC, you don't need to create an empty dynamic Enumerable.  You should be able to iterate over the original data you bring back, itself, into a single 'Activity' model you could create in the 'Models' folder:

```
public class Activity {
         public int distance { get; set; };
         public int duration { get; set; }; 
         public bool hasStartTime { get; set; }; 
         public DateTime startTime { get; set; }; 
         public int calories { get; set; };
         public int steps { get; set; };
}
```

Then:

```
List<Statistic> statistics = new List<Statistic>();
IEnumerable<Activity> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content);

foreach(var a in data)
{
    statistics.Add( new Statistic()
    {
            ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Device = context.Device.Where(d => d.Name == "Fitbit").Single(),
            Timestamp = DateTime.Today,
            Type = context.StatisticType.Where(s => s.Type == "calories_eaten").Single(),
            User = user,
            Value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parsedData)
            Distance = a.distance,
            Duration = a.duration,
            StartTime = a.startTime,
            Calories = a.calories,
            Steps = a.steps
     });
}
return statistics; // or do whatever you were going to do with this, here
```